# I can't use System.Net.Http.HttpMethod's properties as switch expression's parameters in C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I encountered this problem in which I can't use `System.Net.Http.HttpMethod`'s properties in a `switch` statement for some reason. Funny thing is I can use it normally within the same method, just outside the `switch` expression. Look at my method:

```cs
private ObjectResult DeterminePositiveResponseType<T>(T response)
{
    Console.WriteLine(HttpMethod.Get.ToString());
    return HttpContext.Request.Method switch
    {
        HttpMethod.Get.ToString() => Ok(response),
        HttpMethod.Post.ToString() => Created("", response)
    };
}
```

The goal is to return appropriate `ObjectResult` depending on what type of request came to the API.

`HttpMethod.Get.ToString()` should just return string `"GET"` and it does within `Console.WriteLine` method. The same piece of code inside switch statement gives error:

> The type name 'Get' does not exist in the type 'HttpMethod'
>
> [image: pic rel]

I have no idea why this happens and would really appreciate if someone can explain it to me. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what your seeing is because `HttpMethod.Get` is not a const value it's a property and I think the switch requires const values.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. See also: [ask]

Comment: @MiB_Coder: The code is also in the question in a `code` block, as is the error message. Presumably, the images is additionally included to illustrate the error detected by Visual Studio's code analysis. This seems like an acceptable use of embedding an image to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
        private ObjectResult DeterminePositiveResponseType<T>(T response)
    {
        var methodType = HttpContext.Request.Method;

        switch (methodType)
        {
            case string m when HttpMethod.Get.ToString() == methodType:
                return Ok(response);
            case string m when HttpMethod.Post.ToString() == methodType:
                return Created("",response);
            default:
                return Ok(response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This approach is nice since it doesn't require hard-coding your property names as strings. That probably isn't an issue here when talking about well-known APIs like `HttpMethod` which are bound by external standards and unlikely to change any time soon. But as a general rule, this helps retain referential integrity in case the interface changes in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

`case` values in `switch` operator should be constants, this means that any `ToString()` in `case` won't work as it will be executed in runtime. You need to define your values explicitly:

```
 return HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod switch
 {
     "GET" => Ok(response),
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using new switch syntax in this way:

```
private ObjectResult DeterminePositiveResponseType<T>(T response)
{
    Console.WriteLine(HttpMethod.Get.ToString());
    return HttpContext.Request.Method switch
    {
        string s when s == HttpMethod.Get.ToString() => Ok(response),
        string s when s == HttpMethod.Post.ToString() => Created("", response)
        _ => Ok(response), //this line to prevent throwing of SwitchExpressionException
    };
}
```